# Passing a string to matlab from command line Linux

Tags: linux, matlab

I want to be able to pass in to a matlab script (or function) an argument which is a string.
It works fine with integers but I cannot do it with Strings.
Example:
/usr/bin/matlab -nodisplay -r 'main('ana')'

I get:
Undefined function or variable 'ana'.

I tried " as well and I get an error.

I have the same issue when main is a script and I write something like:

/usr/bin/matlab -nodisplay -r 'a='ana';main'.

Can you please tell me how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `"` as delimiter for the command string:

```
/usr/bin/matlab -nodisplay -r "a='ana';main"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to run: `/usr/bin/matlab -r "main('blabla')"`

Comment: Thank you! I realised it eventually!